# R Shiny: reactivevalues from function

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I stored several tables in .rds files which I would like to import using readRDS in a Shiny session. Therefore I defined the following global function:

```
get.station <- function(sname){
  file.name <- paste(sname".rds", sep="")
  return(readRDS(file.name))
}
```

within the server function I define the reactive value:

```
st.reactive <- reactiveValues(get.station(input$station.sel))
```

where `input$station.sel` comes from the ui using `selectInput(...)`. This results in the following error message:

```
Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. 
(You tried to do something that can only be done from inside 
a reactive expression or observer.)
```

This error message even does not disappear if I define this function using `reactive()`:

```
get.station <- reactive({
    file.name <- paste(input$station.sel".rds", sep="")
    return(readRDS(file.name))
  })
```

and within the server:

```
st.reactive <- reactiveValues(data=get.station())
```

Do you have any help?

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea, just put the function inside a `reactive` or `observe_` function. While you can define `reactiveValues` in the initial call, its best, in my opinion, to create the reactive values object empty and then do all your assignments with the `<-` notation.

The confusion comes from the fact that, despite it's name, `reactiveValues` is not a reactive expression. It generates a reactiveValues object that reactive values can be stored in, but it only runs once and does not check whether its values are invalidated.

In your case, I'd do the following:

```
rv <- reactiveValues()
rv$st.reactive <- observe({get.station(input$station.sel)})
```